# Setting created and modified dates for Sharepoint 2010 list items

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm working on a Powershell script to migrate data from an existing SQL Server database into Sharepoint 2010 lists.  Some of the records in the existing database have created and modified dates which the client would like to carry over into Sharepoint.

My migration script uses the UpdateListItems method on Sharepoint Lists web service to upload batches of CAML to create the new items.  I have updated my CAML to set the "Created" column however the value seems to get ignored and is just set to the current date.

Is it possibly to manually set these dates either through the web services or through the ProcessBatchData method on the SPWeb object?  I've seen examples online which imply that it can be done for individual items by disabling system update and tweaking versioning settings.  However working with individual items is not an option since we have about 800,000 list items to import.

Comment: i don't think this is possible via the SharePoint web services.. your only option seems to be the server object model.

Comment: Using the API isn't a problem - I would prefer not to rewrite but its not a huge deal.  Adding list items individually isn't an option since the process just takes too long.  If there was some method of allowing it temporarily across the whole site I could probably use SPWeb.ProcessBatchData and give it my XML.

Comment: Oh this is what you meant with 'individually', now i understood ;-) Every method you could possible use to add this many items will be slow, but i don't see why you can't add them individually, are you getting a timeout? You also might consider splitting your data in different lists, because even if 800,000 items isn't even close the the lists limit, it's going to be so amazingly slow that you might want to pull your hairs out ;-)

Comment: I'd suggest you use the Business Connectivity Services which has been introduced with SharePoint 2010. Basically, they allow you to load the contents of you SQL server table in your SharePoint list dynamically, so the data can be modified/altered/displayed with the default SharePoint interface, but the data source remains SQL. See this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819133.aspx

Comment: It's not timing out but it takes an unreasonable amount of time.  This was the original approach used and we left it to run over night but it still wasn't even close to being finished.  The data is spread across several lists but one specific list does account for 500,000 items.  I've taken a look at the Business Connectivity Services which seems great however I'm not sure its suitable in our situation.

Comment: ok i understand.. well your only option seems to be ProcessBatchData. I'd estimate roughly 2sec / 100 items until you hit the 5000 items threshold then the time will increase. In the XML you can specify the columns you want to add/update, setting the CreatedDate/ModifiedDate works (tested it on my dev machine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to change from using web services to using SPWeb.ProcessBatchData to import my data (thanks Andreas).

The XML passed into this method looks like:

```
<ows:Batch OnError="Continue">
  <Method ID="1">
    <SetList />
    <SetVar Name="ID">New</SetVar>
    <SetVar Name="Cmd">Save</SetVar>
    <SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#ColumnName1">Value</SetVar>
    <SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Modified">2009-09-03T15:05:00Z</SetVar>
    <SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Created">2004-01-15T13:48:00Z</SetVar>
  </Method>
  <Method ID="2">
    ...
  </Method>
  ...
</ows:Batch>
```

The "SetList" element should contain the Guid for the list to add the data too.  In my example XML above this is empty because the XML is pre-generated before importing the data into SharePoint and we can't guarantee that the Sharepoint list Guid on the target server would be the same so we fill this in just before importing.

I also had to ensure that the dates being passed in where in the correct format by passing them into the SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime method.